# Calculate time between 2 TDateTime, with a twist

Tags: c++, time, c++builder, tdatetime

I need to find out how to get the time between 2 times, but only if it is within work hours(Stored in a database)

This is what I got for now, but it is totally wrong. the total won't bee correct.

```
int __fastcall Organisasjon::CalculateResponsetimeInOpeninghours(std::auto_ptr<DBCommand> cmd, long orgid, TDateTime starttimeIn, TDateTime endtimeIn)
{
int totalTimeInQueue = 0;
String sIsWorkDay = "";

String s  =  "SELECT o.isworkday, o.workdate, o.workstarttime, o.workendtime " \
                 "FROM orgwdexcep o " \
                 "WHERE o.workdate = :date " \
                 "AND o.orgid = :orgid ";
String s2 =  "SELECT o.isworkday, o.workdate, o.workstarttime, o.workendtime " \
                 "FROM globalwodexcep o " \
                 "WHERE o.workdate = :date ";
String s3 =  "SELECT o.workstarttime, o.workendtime " \
                 "FROM organizationworkday o " \
                 "WHERE o.weekdayindex = :weekdayindex " \
                 "AND o.orgid = :orgid ";
double MailThisDayStart = starttimeIn;
double MailThisDayEnd = endtimeIn;

while ((int)MailThisDayStart <= (int)endtimeIn)
{//for each day i period.
    if((int)MailThisDayStart != (int)endtimeIn)
    {
        MailThisDayEnd = (double)((long)MailThisDayEnd) + 1;
}
    cmd->setCommandText(s);
    cmd->Param( "date" ).setAsDateTime() = DBDatabase::ConvertToSADateTime(MailThisDayStart);
    cmd->Param("orgid").setAsLong() = orgid;
    cmd->Execute();
    if (!(cmd->isResultSet() && cmd->FetchNext()))
    {
        cmd->setCommandText(s2);
        cmd->Param( "date" ).setAsDateTime() = DBDatabase::ConvertToSADateTime(MailThisDayStart);
        cmd->Execute();
    }
    if(cmd->isResultSet() && cmd->FetchNext())
    {
      sIsWorkDay = String(cmd->Field("isworkday").asString());
    }
    else
    {
        int dayOfTheWeek = DayOfTheWeek(MailThisDayStart);
        cmd->setCommandText(s3);
        cmd->Param("weekdayindex").setAsLong() = dayOfTheWeek;
        cmd->Param("orgid").setAsLong() = orgid;
        cmd->Execute();
        if(cmd->isResultSet() && cmd->FetchNext())
        {
            sIsWorkDay = "T";
  }
    }
    if(sIsWorkDay == "T")
    {
        TDateTime tmpOpeningStart =  TDateTime(cmd->Field("workstarttime").asDateTime());
        TDateTime tmpOpeningEnd = TDateTime(cmd->Field("workendtime").asDateTime());
        double dtmpOpeningStart = tmpOpeningStart- (int)tmpOpeningStart;
        double dtmpOpeningEnd = tmpOpeningEnd- (int)tmpOpeningEnd;

        totalTimeInQueue +=  Organisasjon::CountHours(MailThisDayStart, MailThisDayEnd, dtmpOpeningStart, dtmpOpeningEnd,(int)MailThisDayStart);
    }
    MailThisDayStart++;//increase date by one
    MailThisDayStart = (double)((long)MailThisDayStart);
}
return totalTimeInQueue;
}

int __fastcall Organisasjon::CountHours(double MailTimeStart, double MailTimeEnd, double openingTimeStart, double openingTimeEnd, int DayToCompute)
{
   if(MailTimeEnd<openingTimeStart)
   {
       return 0;
       }
   if(MailTimeStart<(DayToCompute+openingTimeStart))
   {
       MailTimeStart=openingTimeStart;
   }
   else
   {
        MailTimeStart=MailTimeStart-(int)MailTimeStart;
   }
   if(MailTimeEnd>(DayToCompute+openingTimeEnd))
   {
    MailTimeEnd=openingTimeEnd;
   }
   else
   {
    MailTimeEnd=MailTimeEnd-(int)MailTimeEnd;
   }
   TDateTime dt = TDateTime((MailTimeEnd - MailTimeStart));
   unsigned short milli;
   unsigned short sec;
   unsigned short min;
   unsigned short hour;
   dt.DecodeTime(&hour,&min,&sec,&milli);
   int total = hour*3600;
   total += min*60;
   total += sec;
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Do the workstarttime and workendtime fields store the working hours or the duration of the email?

Comment: workstarttime and workendtime stores the opening hours of the organization on the given date, organizationworkday look like this: id, orgId, weekDay, workStartTime, workEndTime.
Params to the method TDateTime starttimeIn, TDateTime endtimeIn is the time for when the email first was registered in the system, and endtime is when someone did answer it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to see in `total`?

Try this example:

```
TDateTime MailTimeEnd = TDateTime::CurrentTime();;
MailTimeEnd += 1.0 / 24;
TDateTime MailTimeStart = TDateTime::CurrentTime();
TDateTime dt = TDateTime((MailTimeEnd - MailTimeStart));
unsigned short milli;
unsigned short sec;
unsigned short min;
unsigned short hour;
dt.DecodeTime(&hour,&min,&sec,&milli);
int total = hour*3600;
total += min*60;
total += sec;
```

`total == 3600`. It's right.

Comment: The total should bee the total seconds that the email has waited in a queue, but only seconds within workhours should be included. an email could have been waiting for days in a queue so the algoritm need to check for openinghours each day.