# C++ calculate difference between dates

Tags: c++, c++builder, datediff, tdatetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking two TDateTime variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386266/checking-two-tdatetime-variables)

I am having trouble calculating the difference between two dates and then displaying the difference. I have posted a previous question.

I am after help with the replaceTime function. I am not sure how/why I need to use this.

Here is my code:

```
TDateTime testFirstDate("11/09/2012");
TDateTime testFirstTime("14:00");

TDateTime testSecondDate("12/09/2012");
TDateTime testSecondTime("16:00");

TDateTime testCombined1 = ReplaceTime(testFirstDate,testFirstTime);
TDateTime testCombined2 = ReplaceTime(testSecondDate,testSecondTime);

TDateTime testDateDifference = testCombined2 - testCombined1;

std::cout << testDateDifference;
```

Comment: You do not need to repost the same question more than once: [Checking two TDateTime variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386266/checking-two-tdatetime-variables)

Comment: And your problem/question is?

Comment: It looks to me as if ReplaceTime is being used to combine a date and a time. You need to combine testFirstDate and testFirstTime and also testSecondDate and testSecondTime before you find the difference, no?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I am wanting to know if the second time and date is later than the first time and date.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense.  The difference of two dates is never a new date!

I suspect that this part is wrong:

```
TDateTime testDateDifference = testCombined2 - testCombined1;
```

The difference of two dates is a period of time--a time span (usually in seconds).  Did you write the implementation for TDateTime yourself?

Comment: It's the implementation of TDateTime of C++ Builder libraries. His code is right, the difference between two dates is another date.

Comment: `Use the System::TDateTime::- to subtract the value specified by the rhs operand from the System::TDateTime::TDateTime object. The rhs operand represents the number of days (including fractional days) to subtract.`  According to the Borland spec, although the type is a TDateTime the rhs operand is technically not a date.  This is how they can get away with operator-() returning a new date.  At least .NET got this right with their DateTime class.